# How to vertically populate each column of listview with lists

Tags: c#

I have data which I import from textfiles, transfer to an sqlite db, then transfer that into LISTS. Now I want to show these lists to the user in a LISTVIEW. Each column should contain a list.

Below, the contents of the second column are perfectly fine. But, the 3rd and the fourth column should be vertically filled with the items that correspond to their color values.

[image]

I.e from the code below, I want to populate the 3rd and 4th column with the MaxLen list and PercentPopList list. (Yes I know that I skipped a column, but i'll fix that later)

I'm new to programming and I cant figure out how to make that work.

```
  ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
              foreach (object o in SeqIrregularities)
              {
                  lvi.SubItems.Add(o.ToString());
                  listView1.Items.Add(lvi);//Adds a new row
                  lvi = new ListViewItem();
              }

              listView1.Items.Add(lvi);//Adds a new row
              lvi = new ListViewItem();

               foreach (object a in MaxLen)
              {
                  lvi.SubItems.Add(a.ToString());
              }

              listView1.Items.Add(lvi);//Adds a new row
              lvi = new ListViewItem();

              foreach (object b in PercentPopList)
              {
                  lvi.SubItems.Add(b.ToString());
              }

              listView1.Items.Add(lvi);//Adds a new row
```

Comment: Is there any relationship to the lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand that you don't have too much experience and cannot easily come up with an algorithm accounting for the suggested modifications; here you have a sample code showing how to extend your code to populate three different columns from 3 different lists:

```
 List<string> SeqIrregularities = new List<string>();
 SeqIrregularities.Add("1");
 SeqIrregularities.Add("2");
 SeqIrregularities.Add("3");

 List<string> MaxLen = new List<string>();
 MaxLen.Add("4");
 MaxLen.Add("5");
 MaxLen.Add("6");

 List<string> PercentPopLis = new List<string>();
 PercentPopLis.Add("7");
 PercentPopLis.Add("8");
 PercentPopLis.Add("9");
 PercentPopLis.Add("10");
 PercentPopLis.Add("11");


 int totItems = SeqIrregularities.Count - 1;
 if (MaxLen.Count - 1 > totItems) totItems = MaxLen.Count - 1;
 if (PercentPopLis.Count - 1 > totItems) totItems = PercentPopLis.Count - 1;

 for (int i = 0; i <= totItems; i++)
 {
     ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
     string item1 = "";
     string item2 = "";
     string item3 = "";

     if (SeqIrregularities.Count - 1 >= i) item1 = SeqIrregularities[i];
     if (MaxLen.Count - 1 >= i) item2 = MaxLen[i];
     if (PercentPopLis.Count - 1 >= i) item3 = PercentPopLis[i];

     lvi.SubItems.Add(item1);
     lvi.SubItems.Add(item2);
     lvi.SubItems.Add(item3);

     listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
 }
```

Comment: This algorithm makes sense and is very clever. The only issue is that the totItems doesn't only apply to one list, as they are NOT the same size :(

I was thinking of combining these lists into 1, and then looping through the combined list (as you suggested above) to populate the listview. Do you think that's reasonable ?

Comment: @user7068 Sure it is reasonable. The whole point of this answer (mainly when there was other pretty valid already in place) was giving you some "practical hint" about how to face the problem. You can either create a collection with all the elements (a DataTable, for instance) and iterate through it; or implement something like what I suggest by correcting it as much as required (for example: if there are different number of elements; make totItems = biggest one and put one condition per list to see if the given "i" is within the limits; that is, check if i<SeqIrregularities.Count...)

Comment: Say I get the biggest element and use it for max iterations. Now obviously the other 2 "i"s for the other lists will be lower than this biggest element. But this means that the lists with the smaller max elements will cause an error because they'll have to loop through a larger element which doesnt exist for them.. well unless I put some if statements in there

Comment: @user7068 my intention was letting it in the basics (such that you can do some work by your own) but what on the hell! it is easier to explain the point in this way: please, take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Haha, I was actually writing code very, very similar to what you posted up there purely from the guidance you provided so thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

Your data is in the wrong format.  Simplifying, you seem to have data like this:

```
var firstColumnValues = new List<int>();
var secondColumnValues = new List<int>();
var thirdColumnValues = new List<int>();
```

While each individual list may make sense on its own, they currently don't relate to each other in any meaningful way.  What you need to do is think about the format of the object which represents one "record" of data.  Still overly-simplified, something like this:

```
class RecordOfValues
{
    public int FirstValue { get; set; }
    public int SecondValue { get; set; }
    public int ThirdValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then you'd just have *one* list of them:

```
var listOfRecords = new List<RecordOfValues>();
```

At this point you would have a list of "records" to bind to the `ListView`.

Comment: So are you saying I should just combine these into one list? Seems clever, but then how would I populate each column with the corresponding sublist ?

How do I populate Individual COLUMNS of a listview with separate sections from my Biglist which will combine everything? Say BigList values 0-10 I want to put into column 1. Then Put values 11-20 into column 2. Theoretically is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: @user7068: You would probably loop through the lists and build an object for each index in the loop, getting a value from each list at that index.  You'll want to do a lot of error checking, though, just in case the lists have different element counts or anything like that.  The sooner in your logic this can be done, the better.  If you could join the data at the point where you *get* the data (from wherever you're getting it), that's ideal.